# Angular Material input Two-way Data Binding with [(ngModel)] is not working in production mode

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have been working on an Angular project. Everything is working in localhost, but when I hosted the project, the two-way binding is not working.
Here is the partial code:

app.module.ts:

```
import { FormsModule , ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatInputModule
    ]
})
```

app.component.html:

```
<mat-form-field>
        <input matInput name="username" #username="ngModel" type="text" placeholder="User name"  [(ngModel)]="profile.username" required >
        <mat-error>This field is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

This code perfectly works in localhost, but it's not working in production mode. Is there anyone who can help me with this, please?

Comment: You will have to create a gist/plnkr with exact versions for anyone to help you debug the prod mode vs non-prod mode builds. Create a minimal github repo.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Simonk  I updated the angular cli and npm  to the latest version and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating both Angular cli and node version to latest will solve the problem. It should work

Answer (score 3):

**your code:**

```
name="username"
```

**the correction:**

```
name="profile.username"
```

Comment: I'm curious, where does `profile` come from in this?

Comment: @catfood `profile` is the property name in his typescript code. He just uses it in     [(ngModel)]="profile.username"